# How to handle errors when resuming a Lua thread (coroutine)

Tags: c, lua

Background: I'm using a Lua thread (coroutine) to process user input from stdin (to allow the program to pause while waiting on data from another FD).  Because it's user input, errors are possible if not probable, e.g. calling a non-existent function.

Question: **Can the Lua thread be recovered so that I can continue to process more data from stdin, or do I have to nuke the thread and create a new one after every error?**

Here's some rough sample/pseudo code of what I'm doing now:

```
while (1) {
  select((max, &read_fds, &write_fds, NULL, NULL);
  for each file descriptor {
    if (read fd is set) {
      read data into a buffer
      if (current fd is stdin)
        process_stdin()
      else if (current fd is from server connection)
        process_remote()
    }
    if (write fd is set) {
      write data on non-blocking fd
    }
  }
}

process_stdin() {
  status=luaL_loadbuffer(L, stdin_buf, len, "stdin");
  if (status == LUA_ERRSYNTAX) {
    /* handle EOF which means more user input needed
     * or print error message for user, this works fine */
  }
  else if (status == 0) {
    status=lua_resume(L, 0);
    if (status != 0 && status != LUA_YIELD) {
      /* Do I nuke the thread or is there another way to recover at this point??? */
    }
  }
}
```

Typically, I would use `pcall` to catch the error and recover, but `pcall` doesn't support the yield in 5.1 (though 5.2 may be a good solution here).  With the `lua_resume` call, I'm running into the following in my session:

```
> no_such_func()
Error: attempt to call global 'no_such_func' (a nil value)
> print("hello world")
Error: cannot resume non-suspended coroutine
```

After the first command, the thread status is set to 2 (`LUA_ERRRUN`).

**Edit:** the error message I'm getting doesn't appear to be because of the unwound stack.  I'm seeing this message from ldo.c which indicates the issue is because the thread state is getting set to 2.

```
  if (L->status != LUA_YIELD && (L->status != 0 || L->ci != L->base_ci))
      return resume_error(L, "cannot resume non-suspended coroutine");
```

So I either need a way to reset the state or avoid having the state change in the first place.  My guess is that I may be stuck with popping the thread off my main stack and recreating a new one, or upgrading to 5.2 so I can yield from a `pcall`.

Comment: Is this actually asynchronous, or the Lua co-routines?

Comment: co-routines, this application is single threaded using Lua coroutines for the yield functionality.

Comment: I went ahead and upgraded to Lua 5.2.  The solution there is to push a `pcall` on the stack, then run `lua_loadbuffer`, and when the `lua_resume` status is 0, you have the check the `pcall` result to see if it was true or false.  Much cleaner than the other options I was looking at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Lua 5.1, you can use [coxpcall](http://coxpcall.luaforge.net/).

Comment: Not ideal, but I think this will do as an answer for 5.1.  It looks like they are wrapping a coroutine inside of the parent coroutine so that suspend/resume's can be passed back and forth, and errors are caught instead of bubbling them up.  Seeing how this isn't ideal, I think it's time for me to try out 5.2.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, throwing an error unwinds the stack inside the coroutine, which means there is no function to jump back into.  (The reference manual says nothing regarding this.)

Seems like you'll have to create a new thread.

Comment: Unwinding the stack is ok.  That print function in the example gets pushed on the stack in the next read from stdin.  But since the thread state is 2, Lua won't run it.

Comment: @BMitch: No, unwinding the stack is _not_ OK: it's the reason why the coroutine cannot be resumed. It is considered finished, because the stack unwounded to the base of the coroutine. Thus the coroutine ended.

Comment: @Nicol Bolas: the coroutine ends every time it finishes processing a line from stdin, and then restarts when you pass it another line (via `luaL_loadbuffer`).  Without errors, the `lua_resume` call is providing similar functionality to `lua_pcall` that's used in lua.c.  The only time my stack isn't empty is if the routine yields, at which point I don't load any more lines until the `lua_resume` stops yielding.