# Wait for Asynchronous Event in Lua

Tags: c#, lua, luainterface

I have a library in Lua that creates and parses data packets for a protocol.  When I send a packet out, I'm expecting a reply back from the destination that is then parsed into a table.  I'm trying to write a wrapper around this library so that I can make a function call like the following: `result = SendUnicast(dest,packetData)` and have the parsed response table returned to result.

My problem is two fold: 1) The incoming message comes in asynchronously and on a different thread than the executing script and 2) the next packet I receive isn't necessarily the response for my request, I have to parse the incoming packet and match a sequence id.

The program flow currently looks something like:

[C# UI Thread]

- Button Click
- Run Lua Script

  - Call SendUnicast
  - Wait For Response

[C# Data Thread]

- Incoming Message

  - Pass message to Lua parser function
  - if sequence matches waiting command, store parsed table, resume blocked

[C# UI Thread]

- Lua scipt returns parsed table

I can't seem to find a good method for blocking the currently executing script (in the UIThread).  Creating a coroutine to be called when the message is parsed and then `while coroutine.status(co) ~= "dead"` seems to kill my lua interpreter.

**EDIT**

I'm marking BMitch's answer as accepted because it is the correct way to handle this issue.  I will warn you, however, that LuaInterface does not support coroutines and I had to add support for them to the C# code myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UI thread, run:

```
while ((status=lua_resume(L_coroutine, 0)) == LUA_YIELD) {
  semaphore_wait(); /* whatever the appropriate C# call is */
}
```

"Wait for response" should look something like:

```
while not results[my_result] do
  coroutine.yield()
end
```

The "incoming message" function should look like the following in Lua:

```
results[cur_result]=parsed_message
```

And finally back in `C#` for the "incoming message", call the appropriate `semaphore_post()` function.

Sorry if my `C#` looks terrible, I'm a `C` programmer on Linux, so I tried to keep that side generic.

Comment: I meant OS threads.  I edited my post to make that more clear.  I only have one Lua state.  I take it Lua doesn't handle it well if you are running code on a state, and then another thread attempts to run other code within that same state?

Comment: Note, you can use `lua_resume` just as you would a `lua_pcall` but see my question for potential issues that can create: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6625698/how-to-handle-errors-when-resuming-a-lua-thread-coroutine

Comment: I can't seem to find a way in the C# binding (LuaInterface) to interact directly with coroutines.  That's a bit of pita.

Comment: That part is getting out of my expertise, but you may get some help if you add `C#` to your tags.

Comment: Also, since Lua is designed for a single threaded environment, you're going to want to put a mutex/lock around the calls to Lua to avoid the threads corrupting each other's Lua stack.